# Richtige Grammatik: "zwischen dem neuen und altem Haus"

Tags: grammaticality

Wie muss ich den folgenden Satz richtig formulieren:

> Ich befinde mich zwischen dem alten und neuem Haus.

Ist das so eventuell sogar schon richtig?
Oder wäre es besser zu schreiben `zwischen dem alten und dem neuen Haus`?

Wie kann man aber die Kurzform schreiben, in welcher also nur ein `dem` vorkommt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dein Satz ist so, wie er geschrieben ist, schon fast richtig (es muss "*neuen* Haus" heißen). Es wird auch klar, dass es sich um zwei verschiedene Häuser handeln muss, zum einen durch das *zwischen*, und zum andern kann ein Haus nicht gleichzeitig alt und neu sein.

In anderen Fällen kann man den zweiten Artikel nicht so einfach weglassen, weil sonst nicht eindeutig ist, ob es sich um ein oder zwei Objekte handelt:

> Der Zoowärter war in dem Gehege bei dem alten und gefährlichen Löwen.

Hier ist nicht klar, ob es sich um zwei Löwen handelt, von denen der eine alt und der andere gefährlich, oder nur um einen Löwen, der beides ist, handelt, bzw. man würde so, wie es formuliert ist, warscheinlich das letztere annehmen.

Es lohnt sich also nicht wirklich, drüber nachzudenken, ob man wegen drei eingesparten Buchstaben den Satz u.U. mißverständlich macht. Die meisten Sprecher würden das zweite "dem" wohl nicht versuchen wegzulassen.

Answer (score 6):

Der Satz ist zwar syntaktisch nicht wirklich falsch, aber ziemlich merkwürdig, da für das alte Haus ein Artikel verwendet wurde, für das neue aber nicht.

Da "neuem" starke Flexion ist, zeigt es die Abwesenheit des Artikels an, es wurde also auch kein Artikel weggelassen.

Es wäre besser, konsistent zu zu verfahren und entweder bei beiden Häusern einen Artikel zu verwenden oder ihn bei beiden wegzulassen.

Also entweder

> Ich befinde mich zwischen dem alten und **dem neuen** Haus.

(m.E. die bessere Variante)

oder

> Ich befinde mich zwischen **altem** und neuem Haus.